# Set Max Cache Size on Disk Android Universal Image Loader

Tags: java, android, image

I am using Android Universal Image Loader in my project. I have 2500+ images in my project which need more than 80 MB disk space. Is there any way I can limit Disk cache size?

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can determine the size of both the memory and disk cache:

From the [library's documentation](http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/72-universal-image-loader-part-2.html)

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new
ImageLoaderConfiguration .Builder(getApplicationContext())
.discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
```

And then the author explains more about the other options for discCache:

> Using discCache(), you can define cash implementation in the file system. You can use ready-made solutions (where the files matching certain URLs are named as hash codes of these URLs):
>
> 1 - UnlimitedDiscCache (usual cache, no restrictions)
>
> 2 - FileCountLimitedDiscCache (cache with limited files number)
>
> 3 - TotalSizeLimitedDiscCache (cache with limited size)

You are also able to have your own implementation of the Disk and memory cache, more information on that in the link i provided earlier.

Comment: Isnt it FileCountLimitedDiscCache (cache with limited files number) and TotalSizeLimitedDiscCache (cache with limited size)?